# How to have separate UI section in Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame

So I have a game, and you can move and attack and move the camera around, etc...but I want to have a section of the screen dedicated to Character info like health, etc.

How do I make a fixed section for that and have the game window next to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a new SpriteBatch draw call, and provide it with a View projection that will draw in screen space instead of world space.

Comment: How do I differentiate between screen space and world space?

Comment: In your SpriteBatch.Begin(), you can specify the projection matrix.